# Where does the "2" in 2^n come from when computing max memory size? n=n-bit

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

So I was reading up on address buses and max memory sizes, so my question is, when computing max memory size for any architecture, where does the 2 in 2^n where n is the address bus bit size come from? Also what does a "bit size" even mean? I'm so confused.

Comment: 2 is the amount of bit states (it may be in state 0 or in state 1).

Comment: If you wonder why the number 2 was chosen for a bit, it comes down to its electrical hierarchy. The earlier processors were huge and used condensators. These either let electricity flow through (1) or block (0). By adding a lot of them in series one can create logic. Over time the size of condensators were shrunk down from several meters to less than centimeters, then the microchip was created and they were moved to the size of microns and smaller, but their function remained the same.

Comment: @LPChip - "condensators"? These are now called capacitors, and I am not aware of computers being made of them. Are you sure you don't mean _vacuum tubes_ also known as _valves_?

Comment: Each architecture uses a number of bits to represent a memory location. The range of this representation is your maximum memory size.

Comment: @LPChip - presumably you mean "condensors", the old name for what we call "capacitors" now? Condensors always allow alternating current through, and never direct current. There's no choice in the matter. So they cannot be used for making computers in the way you imagine.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and assume LPChip speaks German, because "Kondensator" is the German term for a "capacitor" in English.

Comment: @Voo It doesn't really matter though, because capacitors are not how you store bit values, nor were they ever how you stored bit values in historical computers.

Comment: I indeed meant condensors, the thing that indeed is now called capacitors

Comment: @Graham But that's not true! [DRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory) basically uses 1 capacitor and 1 transistor per bit, and AFAIK DRAM is the dominant source of volatile memory today. And indeed the charge storage ability of a capacitor is exactly how these cells hold data (and it also explains why they lose their state when you cut the power). That said, we don't usually use capacitors for the logic elements of a processor.

Comment: The number 2 was not chosen for a bit, the word "bit" was chosen for the number 2! Otherwise we'd be talking about [trits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system#Trit) or whatever else

Comment: @Graham - Beg to differ.  Capacitors were (and maybe still are) common in early semiconductor RAM (and likely in tube-based systems as well).

Comment: @Nacht the word bit was not chosen for the number 2, bit means binary digit, which is 0 or 1.

Comment: @barlop Yes and where does the word "binary" come from?

Comment: @barlop My point is that the "bi-" root word is used for things that relate to the number 2. So yes, the word "bit" was chosen because it has two values.

Comment: Well, they tried 1 but literally couldn't get anywhere and 3 was proving a bit more messy than what it was worth. Quantum computing is betting that not knowing the number is much better and they are probably right.

Comment: @Nacht Hmm where did my comment disappear to re the etymology of the word "binary"  when you asked where the word came from.

Answer (score 45):

2 comes from the nature of binary numbers, where there are exactly 2 possible states per digit.

When calculating the number of values a given number of digits can contain, the calculation is always `Options^Instances`. *Options* represent the set of  possible choices a digit could have, and *Instances* represents the number of digits being used (length, width, and size are common synonyms).

Likewise, to calculate the range of values that could be stored, it is `0 -> (Options^Instances) - 1`.

Note that digit values are always [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), so we're not worried about negative numbers or decimals or anything more exotic. Those concepts build atop digit values to augment their meaning, but the underlying value representation is unchanged. 3, -3, and 3.3 all express different meanings, but they all use the digit value 3 in the same way with the same rules.

So a 2-bit number can express 4 possible values, ranging from 0 to 2^2-1 (0-3). Ie. the set of possible values is `{00, 01, 10, 11}`.

a digit of [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) contains 2 options, so it is Base-2. Most common number systems in use these days have 10 options per digit (0-9), so they are Base-10. Other common bases include [Octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base-8) and [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (base-16).

This concept isn't even limited to numbers, but any well designed set of values. If I wanted to calculate the the number of possible 8-character passwords consisting of all lower case Latin letters, it would be 26^8. If I added capital letters, it would be 52^8. If I then added numbers, it would be 62^8. For binary numbers however, since it can only be 0 or 1, it's always 2^n.

Bit-size refers to the number of bits used to store a value (the "Instances" variable). For a real-world example, the game No Man's Sky uses a 32-bit number to represent money, so you can never get more than ‭4,294,967,295 money. That's because it's the maximum value you can express in 32 bits.

Comment: It should probably be stated that this is the numerical "base" as in binary is base-2, decimal is base-10, and so on. This may give hints for future research and learning about numerical systems and the reason for the 2^n and 10^n.

Comment: ...and that the word "bit" is a contraction of "binary digit", which is either 0 or 1

Comment: I believe that's the maximum number of studs in the Wii 'Lego' games, too. I'd never really considered that it was 32-bit limitation.

Comment: Ah, but the wave of the future is TRENARY!!

Comment: You say "This concept isn't even limited to numbers, but any well designed set of values." I *think* you mean well designated, as in, "it has to be one of these possibilities". The possibilities can be as poorly designed as you like, so long as they're consistent. ;)

Comment: well to calculate a range,ordinality is required, so that is part of my definition of well-designed, but yeah, that is correct.

Answer (score 30):

Here's an attempt at "explain it like I'm 5" type of answer.

A single bit has two states: `0` and `1`. Using a single bit I can store two values:

```
0
1
```

By adding a single bit we can store four values. Let's ignore that they are binary numbers, just keep in mind that they are distinct values:

```
00
01
10
11
```

Add another one and we have eight values:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Why are they doubling? Imagine you're prepending the new bit to the left. If the bit is 0, you get previous set of  four values but prefixed by 0. If it's 1, you get previous set of four values prefixed by 1. That's 8 total: 4 previous values times 2 possible states of the added bit.

```
 previous bits  |    previous bits
 ↓↓             |    ↓↓
000             |   100
001             |   101
010             |   110
011             |   111
↑               |   ↑
new '0' bit     |   new '1' bit
```

Here's a graphical version, if you don't like ASCII art:

[image: Original four values (two bytes each), one per row, are duplicated. Then a 0 is prepended to each value in the first group of four and a 1 is prepended to each value in the second group.]

If we had three possible states for the prepended "bit" ("trit"?), let's say `A`, `B` and `C`, we'd triple the number of possible values:

```
 previous bits  |    previous bits  |    previous bits
 ↓↓             |    ↓↓             |    ↓↓
A00             |   B00             |   C00
A01             |   B01             |   C01
A10             |   B10             |   C10
A11             |   B11             |   C11
↑               |   ↑               |   ↑
new 'A' bit     |   new 'B' bit     |   new 'C' bit
```

[image: An image similar to the previous one, but now there are three copies of original four values. First four are prepended with state 'A', next four with 'B' and final four with 'C'.]

So adding a new bit to the value multiplies number of possible values by number of states this new bit can have. First bit has 2 states (`0` and `1`), so a 1-bit number has 2 values. Second bit has two states:

```
2 × 2 = 4
↑   ↑
↑    number of 2nd bit's states
↑
 number of 1st bit's states
```

Third bit has two states too:

```
4 × 2 = 8
↑   ↑
↑    number of 3rd bit's states
↑
 number of previous values
```

Same with the fourth bit:

```
8 × 2 = 16
↑   ↑
↑    number of 4th bit's states
↑
 number of previous values
```

We can expand the 8 in this formula to our previous calculations:

```
((2 × 2) × 2) × 2 = 16
  ↑   ↑    ↑    ↑
  ↑   ↑    ↑     number of 4th bit's states
  ↑   ↑    ↑
  ↑   ↑     number of 3rd bit's states
  ↑   ↑
  ↑    number of 2nd bit's states
  ↑
   number 1st bit's states
```

As you can see, to get the number of possible values, you have to multiply numbers of states of particular bits. Since all of our bits have 2 states, we can simplify multiplying 2's `n` times to a simply 2<sup>n</sup>.

Comment: Fun fact: Ternary computers [actually existed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer#History) and Donald Knuth once said he thought they'd make a a comeback.

Comment: Another fun fact that is marginally related: you can express complex numbers [using only the digits 0,1,2,3 in the quater-imaginary base -2i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quater-imaginary_base)

Comment: This answer is outstanding. Step-by-step. Care and effort was put into this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Let me complement the existing answers with an analogy: How many different numbers (let's call them **addresses**) can you build with an `n`-digit number?

Let's try:

- 2 digits can build addresses from 00 to 99, which are 100 addresses.
- 3 digits can build addresses from 000 to 999, which are 1000 addresses.
- ...
- In general, `n` digits can build `10^n` addresses.

That's because one (decimal) digit has 10 possible states (0-9, latin *decem* = ten).

**Bits** are like digits, except that they only have 2 states (0 and 1). Hence, `n` bits can build `2^n` addresses.

Answer (score 4):

CPUs talk to RAM through their address and data pins.  Here's an example from an old 8-bit CPU called a 6502.

[image]

The A pins are the address pins and the D pins are the data pins.

There's 16 A pins, numbered 0 through 15.

Each pin can be **ON** or **OFF** (nothing in between), so that's 2 possible states per pin.

So there's 2^16 possible states, or 65,536 possible addresses.

The D pins are used to send (write) or get (read) the data from the address.  Since there's 8 of them, you can read/write 2^8 possible values (0-255).

Modern CPUs are [more complicated](https://www.reenigne.org/blog/what-are-all-those-pins-for/) because they talk to the RAM with multiple channels and signaling for modern RAM is more complicated due to its speed, but it's essentially the same concept.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the answers are trying to explain the "binary" side of this, but it may not be clear how that connects to the computer architecture. Computers work with bits in chunks that are called "words". In modern computers, a word is typically 64 bits, and for a long time the standard word size was 32 bits. When you have an integer or unsigned integer data type, one word of bits is all you get. You can work with larger numbers if you write software to do the arithmetic, but that's not built into the machine like single-word integer types are.

This is important because every memory location has an address which is just a number. Suppose you were working with a 1980s machine with 16-bit words. For unsigned integers, you can represent 2^16 different integers, and so those are all the memory addresses you can have. It's like noticing that there can only be ten billion phones in the US and Canada because phone numbers only have ten digits. (Fewer really, because of limits on valid phone numbers.)

With 64-bit machines, you can address far more memory than you could ever provide, but for a long time address space was a real limiting factor.

This oversimplifies in places, but I hope it gives the right overall idea.

Comment: +1 for covering words

Comment: This is good on explaining what bit size means but leaves the "2" question unanswered. The "2" is due to the "bit states" as another answer (@Akina; more votes) mentions

Answer (score 1):

> Also what does a "bit size" even mean?

By itself, nothing.

But in "address bus bit size" it is the size of the bus:

- the 6502 has an address bus of 16 bits (and 2^16 means max 64 kB RAM and ROM)
- the 8086 has an address bus of 20 bits (and 2^20 is up to 1 MB)
- the 80386 has an address bus of 32 bits (4 GB)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the main question, as I think others have covered that more than adequately above, but specifically expanding on:

> Also what does a "bit size" even mean?

In generally it means the number of binary digits (bits) that can be used to represent a particular thing. In this case it is the number of bits that can be used to express an address in memory. Using 8 bits you can count from 00000000 to 11111111 which is 0 to 255 in decimal, so an address bus of size 8 would be able to support memory 256 slots long (one slot is usually a byte, 8 bits, though there are some uncommon architectures where this is not the case).

It can be important to realise that there can be several different "bit sizes" associated with a CPU and its surrounding electronics. When we describe an X-bit CPU we are almost always referring to the size of its largest general purpose registers and its integer arithmetic units. The 80386 CPU, at least in its initial variants, was entirely 32-bit: it had 32-bit general purpose registers (so natively could count to 2^32, or from -2^31 to 2^31-1 if using signed numbers), a 32-bit data bus (so could read up to 32-bits at a time from memory into one of those registers), and a 32-bit address bus (so could directly address 2^32 bytes, 4GB, of memory). The Pentium Pro is a much more mixed bag: considered a 32-bit processor because its general purpose registers and primary arithmetic units were that size, it had a 36 bit address bus (so could directly address 64Gb) and a 64-bit data bus (while this doesn't directly help loading 32-bit registers, it meant the Pentium could fill its on-chip cache faster). The 80386SX was similarly mixed: 32-bit internals, 24-bit address bus, 16-bit data bus. There are other complications too (floating point, vector registers, segmented addressing, memory paging, ...) but covering those would be straying even further off-topic.

Comment: I'm nit picking here, but a signed 32-bit 2's complement integer can represent values from -2^31 to 2^31-1, not -2^32 to 2^32-1. An unsigned 32-bit integer can only represent values up to 2^32-1.

Comment: @EvilTak - as yes, typo on my part, thanks for spotting, will correct.

Answer (score 1):

As a computer engineer, I personally feel that none of the current answers quite answer the asked question, although a few get close.

So, in order:

2^n gives the range of numbers that is accessible with n bits (though Groonostaj does do a bit better at explaining this part). This is because a bit is a *B*inary *D*igit, or a single place in a number system that only has two numbers to count with (0 and 1, compared to 0-9 in Decimal, for a total of two digits). The range is thus basically asking how many unique numbers may be produced with the specified places in that number system. As stated in another answer, this is done with exponents. One place holds as many potential values as there are digits, two contains digits x digits, three contains digits x digits x digits...

In shorthand, those would be digits^1, digits^2, and digits^3. Since this is binary, digits=2, so we have 2^places, and places is usually given as n since in a computer, there's a physical count of them as I'll get to next.

Now, the address bus bit size is a bit simpler (and again, Heinzi captures the essence of this). You can think of memory as something like a long line of boxes, each given a number. You can add or remove things to those boxes, but you must know what box you want to actually open first. Since computers use binary, the number must be represented as 1s or 0s. But, and this is the important part, there must be enough physical space to store the box number. Think of it like a Scantron sheet (and this is actually how those work, for that matter). Each dot on the Scantron stores one place of the binary number, and if there aren't enough places the computer is unable to access higher box numbers (memory addresses) in that row. The address bus bit size is thus simply the number of bits in the register (and eventually the physical bus wire count going to the RAM) that tells the memory what address to find. Once you've used up all the wires' possible states in allocating memory, the computer can't access any more, even if it's present. (Plus, the socket may well be incompatible, since there would be a different number of wires on each side. At best some would just be grounded out to make them unused.)

The whole thing is an issue simply because computers don't actually comprehend numbers at all. First, binary was chosen because it's either true or false, 1 or 0. The designers didn't have to worry about perfectly replicating voltage levels for an infinite-precision analog system or comparing more-ish to less-ish voltages (which would further vary with supply voltage fluctuations), which computers have always been fairly bad at storing or comparing. What you think of as a number, the computer sees as a pattern of wires that happen to have 0v or 5v (we now have much more esoteric voltages with high-efficiency CPUs, but this was traditional for a long time) on them. The wires' values are then fed to a set of AND and OR gates that would first isolate the specific pattern sent via those wires and then provide the stored value that is associated with that pattern (if this does not make it clear enough, computer design is *tedious*). Without enough wires, the computer simply can't process (again, note that I did not say "understand") a number. It can get a bit more complicated because the memory may not have the same number of data bits stored per address as there are address bits to find that data, or because not all parts of a computer are actually made of logic gates as you'd understand them, but that's an answer for a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The etymology of ***bit*** is *Binary Digit* (or as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) puts it, it's a *Portmanteau*).

When you were a kid, someone taught you to count to 10 on your fingers (aka digits).  That's why we tend to count in base 10; ten just seems so reasonable.

But, you can also look at your fingers as binary digits.  They have two states, folded or extended.  If all of the fingers of one hand are folded (as in a fist), it can represent the number 0.  Now extend your pinky finger (the least significant digit).  That's one.

Fold the pinky down and extend the (ring) finger next to it.  That can represent 2, since this is base two arithmetic, "10" represents "one two and zero ones".  Extend the pinky back up and you get "11" (one two and one one, so 3).

Fold both of those fingers down, and raise your middle finger.  This rude pose represents "100" - i.e., one four, no twos and no ones (since 4 is two squared, just like 100 is ten squared). Keep counting like this and you get 101 (5), 110 (6) and 111 (7).  Eventually, you will have all five of your fingers extended ("11111") and you will get two the fifth minus 1, or 31.

This is because one of your hands can display a 5 bit number (0 through 31) - it has 5 binary digits - it's a 5-bit bus.  Work with both hands and you will have 10 bits, and you will be able to represent 1024 discrete finger positions (zero through 1023, where 1023 is two to the tenth minus one).

And, if you are like me, you'll teach your kid how to count past 1000 on her fingers when she's in 2nd or 3rd grade.  This will result in questions on teachers' night.