# are page tables under utilized in x86 systems

Tags: linux, memory, unix, operating-systems, x86

I was recently looking at the page table architecture in x86 and x86-32 machines.

x86-32 paging architecture:
[image: x86-32 paging architecture]

x86-64 paging architecture:
[image: x86-64 paging architecture]

In x86 for example, we use 10 bits as offset into the page directory/page table. This means we can index 1K entries in a page directory/page table. But given that page directory and page table addresses have to be page aligned os's have to allocate 4K memory for page directories/tables

Is my understanding correct/ did I mess up the math somewhere.

If my understanding is correct, I have two followups

1. If we have a lot of processes in a system( and thereby a lot of page directories and tables) isn't this a lot of wasted memory
2. Are there any OS implementations that do interesting things with this 3k memory thats inaccessible

Comment: Is there a practical problem you're trying to resolve?

Comment: Some aspects of this are discussed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1735411/714576)